# При нажатии на кнопку снизу показать DIV и закрыть DIV!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ребята, подскажите какой каким образом функцией открыть при клике на кнопку и скрыть div !?

```
<button class="btn">Кликни по мне</button>
<div class="div1"></div>
```

---

хз может так попробывать четед добавление класса на дисплей блок

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
            $(".div1").toggleClass("div1_active");  
    });
```

Comment: я вас правильно понимаю, что при клике на кнопку вы хотите, чтоб если div сейчас видим, то его надо скрыть, и наоборот если он в данный момент не видим, то его надо отобразить?

Comment: Да, изначально div не видно он скрыт. Нажимаем на кнопку и он становится виден хотел сделать через .slideToggle() , да что то не получается!

Comment: 1.Надо задать идентификаторы кнопке и элементу div.  2 В css прописать свойства для классов видимого элемента div и для скрытого. 3 написать скрипт, который будет реагировать на нажатие кнопки и менять атрибут class в элементе div.

Comment: помогите с написанием скрипта, я так понял там через display: none и block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".div1").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Кликни по мне</button>
<div class="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Класс, это оно! Только что бы div был закрыт с самого начала. Как это сделать ?

Comment: @hulkroarTkachenko На здоровье. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, как долго я Вас ждал )))

Answer (score 0):

Если состояние div: "закрыт" / "открыт" определяется стилевым свойством display: none; то задача решается быстрее, чем вы составляли свой вопрос.

```
let div = document.querySelector('.div1');

  document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.style.display = getComputedStyle(div).display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  });
```